# how to use unique_together in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

i have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    cost=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.TextField(blank=True)
    color=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image_urls=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    source=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    size=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fit=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fabric=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    type_dress=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    currency=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    advertiser=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=('title','source')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want my title and source to be unique together like a composite primary key,but when i do the above changes it was showing the following error on running the django `manage.py syncdb..`

```
NameError: name 'unique_together' is not defined
```

Comment: when i was doing python manage.py syncdb it was showing error that unique_together is not defined

Comment: Post the full traceback (Hint: `--traceback`).

Comment: NameError: name 'unique_together' is not defined

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: i don't know how to check that can you please tell me the way of checking it in that way

Comment: @user2911386 as Ignacio mentioned you should provide the full traceback..

Comment: what db are you using

Comment: do you have a tab/space issue going on in your editor?

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the actual error but i suppose using unique_together is pointless when both fields are also unique.

Comment: Replace `unique_together=('title','source')` to `unique_together=(('title', 'source'),)`. Re-creating database structure may be required.